# Regex match closest <br> tags with a group of words in between

Tags: html, regex

I have been trying to figure this out to no avail. I have looked at many resources online and some get close but not exact. Let's say I have the following code:

```
<br>
Message 1
<br>
<br>
Here is Message 2
<br>
<br>
Here is Message 2 (again)
<br>
```

What I want to do is return all the Message 2's and the text between the closest break tags. The following regex is close:

```
<br>[\s\S]*?Message 2[\s\S]*?<br>
```

However, it returns the following two blocks. Block 1:

```
<br>
Message 1
<br>
<br>
Here is Message 2
<br>
```

Block 2:

```
<br>
Here is Message 2 (again)
<br>
```

However, I need block 1 to return:

```
<br>
Here is Message 2
<br>
```

The messages I receive are always presented in this manner so I don't really think I need an HTML parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex pattern:

```
<br>((?!<br>)[\s\S])*Message 2((?!<br>)[\s\S])*<br>
```

### Demo

The trick I use here is to temper the `.*` with a negative lookahead which asserts that what follows is not a marker `<br>` tag.  In other words, `((?!<br>).)*` will consume everything up to an excluding the next `<br>` tag.

As a disclaimer, in general we should not use regex to parse HTML data.  Sometimes, we are force to do this, e.g. if we are using an editor like Notepad++ which doesn't have an HTML parser.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you.